# getJSON $.each not showing value

Tags: ajax, json, getjson

I have the following getJSON that calls an MVC controller which returns inforamtion back:

```
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("List", "Spkr")',
              { id: spkrid},
            function (data) {

                     $.each(data.spk, function () {
                               alert(spk.ID);
                      });
     });
```

The JSON object looks like the following:
        {"spk":[{"ID":31,"Title":"SprkTitle","Status":"Onlne"}]}

The .each is not showing the anything in the alert. Not sure if I have it configured wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no definition/declaration of spk
the $.each method can take a function like `function(index, value)` as the second parameter where index is the index of the current item and value is its value i.e. data.spk[index == value
So this should work

```
$.each(data.spk, function (index, spk) {
    alert(spk.ID);
});
```

Comment: Hi Musa. Still no luck. I added function (index, spk)

Comment: @NatePet are you sure are getting that json string from the server?

Comment: Yes, I am positive. When I did alert(JSON.stringify(data)); I got the following: {"spk":[{"ID":31,"Title":"SprkTitle","Status":"Onlne"}]}

Comment: OK- got it working. Thanks. it was spkr not spk. Thanks agtain